# process.env.npm_package_version is missing when building for production using vite

Tags: npm, vite

I'm trying to access `process.env.npm_package_version` in `vite.config.ts`. It works in dev, but in production it's says that it's undefined.

```
export default defineConfig({
    define: {
      __VERSION__: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
    },
});
```

Having logged process.env, all the NPM env vars are missing in production. Is there any way to access it?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to get the version would be the following:

```js
import * as fs from 'node:fs'

const packageJson = fs.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf-8')
const version = JSON.parse(packageJson).version
```